# Regex to match URL's not ending in jpg or png

Tags: regex

So here is what I got so far:

```
(?<=\s|\b)https?://[^ ]+(?<!jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)(?=\s|\b)
```

Problem is, it's matching this:

`http://imgur.com/test/img.jpg` (Up to the img). I want it to return no matches.

So basically, these should match:

```
http://test.com/index.html
https://anything.net/this
check out this link: https://anything.net/this it's really cool
```

And these shouldn't match:

```
http://imgur.com/ixmas.jpg
http://example.com/testdirectory/rawr-gif.gif
testhttp://example.com/rawr
```

Comment: Thanks georg for edit.

Comment: Do you need to select urls from text or just match the url as a string?

Comment: I need to match the url as a string from a block of text. `check out this link: https://anything.net/this it's really cool` should match `https://anything.net/this`.

Comment: At the end, tack on a `(?<!jpg)(?<!png)`. That will find all the above but then when it hits the end, looks backward to be sure that it didn't also capture those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Negative Lookahead** instead of Negative Lookbehind.

```
\bhttps?://(?!\S+(?:jpe?g|png|bmp|gif))\S+
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ6bD5/3)

Comment: This seems to fail for a valid url followed by an invalid one, e.g. `https://anything.net/this and http://imgur.com/test/img.jpg`